# Changing public url in knative service definition

Tags: kubernetes, knative, knative-serving

i'm playing around with knative currently and bootstrapped a simple installation using gloo and glooctl. Everything worked fine out of the box. However, i just asked myself if there is a possibility to change the generated url, where the service is made available at.

I already changed the domain, but i want to know if i could select a domain name without containing the namespace, so `helloworld-go.namespace.mydomain.com` would become `helloworld-go.mydomain.com`.

The current YAML-definition looks like this:

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1alpha1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
  name: helloworld-go
  namespace: default
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/knative-samples/helloworld-go
        env:
        - name: TARGET
          value: Go Sample v1
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: not an answer, but under the required reputation to comment currently. in Gloo we are currently tracking the ability to customize the match criteria for Knative routing: https://github.com/solo-io/gloo/issues/2410

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is configurable via the `ConfigMap` named `config-network` in the namespace `knative-serving`. See the ConfigMap in the [deployment resources](https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.8.0/serving.yaml):

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  _example: |
    ...
    # domainTemplate specifies the golang text template string to use
    # when constructing the Knative service's DNS name. The default
    # value is "{{.Name}}.{{.Namespace}}.{{.Domain}}". And those three
    # values (Name, Namespace, Domain) are the only variables defined.
    #
    # Changing this value might be necessary when the extra levels in
    # the domain name generated is problematic for wildcard certificates
    # that only support a single level of domain name added to the
    # certificate's domain. In those cases you might consider using a value
    # of "{{.Name}}-{{.Namespace}}.{{.Domain}}", or removing the Namespace
    # entirely from the template. When choosing a new value be thoughtful
    # of the potential for conflicts - for example, when users choose to use
    # characters such as `-` in their service, or namespace, names.
    # {{.Annotations}} can be used for any customization in the go template if needed.
    # We strongly recommend keeping namespace part of the template to avoid domain name clashes
    # Example '{{.Name}}-{{.Namespace}}.{{ index .Annotations "sub"}}.{{.Domain}}'
    # and you have an annotation {"sub":"foo"}, then the generated template would be {Name}-{Namespace}.foo.{Domain}
    domainTemplate: "{{.Name}}.{{.Namespace}}.{{.Domain}}"
    ...
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    serving.knative.dev/release: "v0.8.0"
  name: config-network
  namespace: knative-serving
```

Therefore, your `config-network` should look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  domainTemplate: {{ '"{{.Name}}.{{.Domain}}"' }}
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-network
  namespace: knative-serving
```

You can also have a look and customize the `config-domain` to configure the domain name that is appended to your services.

Comment: Hi Utku, thanks for the reply. This is a big help. But if i get you right, there is now way to define a domain template at service-level?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any way to define it at the service-level.

Comment: Allright but already this gives me more flexibility. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running knative over an istio service mesh, there's an example of how to use an Istio `Virtual Service` to accomplish this at the service level in the [knative docs](https://github.com/knative/docs/blob/main/docs/serving/samples/knative-routing-go/routing.yaml).